# How to route object using asp-route-paramName

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, view

I am using asp-route-paramName in my view:

```
<btn class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="ChangePrivacy" asp-controller="AdminManager"
     asp-route-to=@UserRolesTypeExtentions.IntValueAsString(@other)
     asp-route-userId=@userRoll.UserId >@other.ToString()</btn>
```

I want to pass enum to the controller so I convert enum to int and then to string. Is there an option to pass object like enum or class (not string) to the controller by using asp-route?

Comment: Just pass the Enum as Enum. No need to convert it to int and string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo like below:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ErrorCode Code { get; set; }
}
public enum ErrorCode
{
    None = 0,
    Unknown = 1,
    ConnectionLost = 100,
    OutlierReading = 200
}
```

View:

The `btn` does not support for tag helper.You need to use a form to call the api:

```
@model Test

<form asp-action="TestEnum" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-to="@Model.Code">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="PassEnum" />
</form>
<form asp-action="TestModel" asp-controller="Home" asp-all-route-data="@(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "to.Code", Model.Code.ToString() },{ "to.UserId",Model.UserId.ToString()} })">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="PassModelWithEnum" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //for easy testing,I set the value by default...
    var model = new Test()
    {
        UserId =1,
        Code = ErrorCode.OutlierReading
    };
    return View(model);
}
public IActionResult TestModel(Test to)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
public IActionResult TestEnum(ErrorCode to)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Result:
[image]